# Why is it I cant access the instance variable in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok so I have this simple class

```
class Test
  @var = 99

  def initialize(var2)
    @var2 = var2
  end 

  attr_reader :var, :var2
end

> t = Test.new(100)
 => #<Test:0x007f9b8118ac30 @var2=100> 
> t.var2
 => 100 
> t.var
 => nil
```

Why is the last `t.var` statement returning nil with I expect it to return 99 because of the `@var = 99` on the top of the class. Maybe my idea of scope is not 100 correct...any ideas on this one

Answer (score 9):

See comments in the code.

```
class Test
  @var = 99 # self is Test class at this point. You're defining 
            # an instance variable on a class instance.

  def initialize(var2)
    @var2 = var2 # This is normal instance variable.
  end 

  attr_reader :var, :var2
end

t = Test.new(100)
t.var # => nil
t.var2 # => 100

# don't bother with creating an accessor and get the ivar from Test directly.
Test.instance_variable_get(:@var) # => 99
```